# How to make HTML input object of event onchange not prompt file explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, blob

Today I have a problem which has 2 ways to work around but I couldn't figure how to properly implement any of them.

I have a HTML element of type file that has an onchange event attached to it. This element is supposed to handle a prompt where the user picks an image file and the image is previewed. Further manipulations are pointless for my problem, so I will not go into them.

Here's where my problem lays: if the user hits the input again (read: after loading an image for the first time) a `confirm` window pops up and he decides whether he wants to replace the current image or not.

If the confirm returns `false` then I DO NOT want the file explorer to pop up and allow the user to pick a new file, which has been happening. If the confirm returns `true` then I DO want the file explorer to pop.

I have tried using an `onclick` event that checked whether the user wanted to replace it or not but I still couldn't prevent the file explorer to pop up. I can, however, if the user says "no" to the confirm window prevent the image from changing.

Here's my code:

**Input that handles the event:**

```
<label class="labelText"> <input id="uploadImage" type="file"
        onchange="PreviewImage();"/> Upload Image
</label>
```

**Javascript functions:**

```
function PreviewImage() {
    var newMapURL = "";

    if(oldMapURL.length == 0){
        oldMapURL  = document.getElementById("uploadImage").value;
        loadImage(newMapURL);
    }
    else {
        newMapURL = document.getElementById("uploadImage").value;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to create a new map?")) {
            cleanWorkspace();
            loadImage(newMapURL);
        }   
    }   
}

function loadImage(newMapURL){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
        reader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("previewImage").src = oFREvent.target.result;       
    }           
}
```

Please note that I want to do this in **pure JavaScript** (read: no jQuery or similar).

Edit: Before anyone mentions, yes I know that `newMapURL` is not being used. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" onchange="PreviewImage();" onclick="return confirm('Sure?')" />
```

You need to make function show confirm only if field is empty and thats it.

Comment: Ok finally with try and error I reached the conclusion that for some reason if I do exactly what you said it works (not exactly the way I want it to, but it does). Since I need extra functionalities to that I need to have it inside a function, but whenever I move it to a function the file explorer fires anyways. Even if my funtion literally contains only the return of the confirm.

Comment: make sure that u have onclick="return func();" not just onclcik="func()"

Comment: Still prompts the file explorer even if it returns false